# RewriteRule for Pretty URLs not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The URLs of my site are of the type

```
http://localhost/cms2/pages.php?mpage=2
```

I have written the following .htaccess in order to create pretty URLs, but nothing happens

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/$ pages.php?spage=$1 [NC]
```

Mod-rewite is ennabled and other rewrite rules I've tested work. For example, I have a file called "contact-us.php". I can make it look "mysite.com/contact-us" using the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Sonia

Comment: What do you want `http://localhost/cms2/pages.php?mpage=2` to look like with the pretty url??

Answer (score 0):

Not working because your regex is incorrect. Use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^./]+)/?$ /cms2/$2.php?spage=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will rewrite a pretty URI: `/3/page/` to `/cms2/page.php?spage=3`